# how to get array element as output in vb asp.net2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In this program I created one array, while clicking on the get Button it does not show any output because the str variable is empty. How should I get proper output...

```
Partial Class dynamic_array
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim s(2) As String

    Dim str As String


    Protected Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
            s(i) = InputBox("enter name " + (i + 1).ToString)
        Next



    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_get_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_get.Click
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        str = ""

        For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
            str &= s(i) + vbCrLf
        Next

        MsgBox(str)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @Terror.Blade now it is visible (code reformat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Session** or **ViewState** to store the Array values..

try like this

```
Partial Class dynamic_array
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim s(2) As String

Dim str As String


Protected Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
        s(i) = InputBox("enter name " + (i + 1).ToString)
    Next



 ViewState("Array")=s

End Sub

Protected Sub btn_get_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_get.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    str = ""
s=  ViewState("Array")
    For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
        str &= s(i) + vbCrLf
    Next

    MsgBox(str)

End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this will help, Mark useful if it's helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net all variables set on the page level are reset on every postback. Thats why s-variable is always empty on get-button click.

You could save this information for example in the [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

```
Viewstate("MyData") = "Something"
```

I encourage you to familiarize your self with Asp.Net web forms basic state management: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50x35554(v=vs.80).aspx